# ggvis layer_boxplots() doesn't work with fill which is not x

Tags: r, ggvis

I'm trying to generate boxplots of `Group` and have the fill by another factor `Species` but it doesn't work. I'm getting a object not found error.

I'm working with `iris`, added a random group factor to it:

```
iris$Group <- as.factor(sample(c("A", "B", "C"), nrow(iris), replace = T))
```

Then plot it with ggviz:

```
iris %>% ggvis(~Group , ~Sepal.Width, fill= ~Species) %>% layer_points()
```

Which works as expected and produces this plot:
[image]

But when I try to generate boxplots I get an error:

```
iris %>% ggvis(~Group , ~Sepal.Width, fill= ~Species) %>% layer_boxplots()

Error in eval(value(x$value), envir = data, enclos = x$env) : 
  object 'Species' not found
```

When I change `x` to `Species` it works as expected:

```
iris %>% ggvis(~Species , ~Sepal.Width, fill= ~Species) %>% layer_boxplots()
```

Produces
[image]
Any idea why? I guess `ggvis` philosophy is different than `ggplot2` but I couldn't figure out how.

Thank you.